# In the language of XXX

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am trying to express a sentence in the language of graph theory. Is that right to say "In the language of graph theory"? I googled and did not find similar sentence. If not, how can I express my meaning?

Comment: In the terms of? In the terminology of? Hard to tell without seeing the context or at least the full sentence.

Comment: If a subject, field of endeavour or profession employs jargon, it would be acceptable to refer to it as the language of ...

Comment: I think "in the terms of" sounds good, but what is the difference between "in the terms of" and "in the terminology of"?

Comment: terms is less verbose than terminology.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply say:

> In graph theory, G denotes a graph.

Or

> In graph terminology...

Answer (score 0):

Graph theory has no proper language, but definitions (often borrowed from ordinary language, where they are used loosely, such as "connective").

I would say "Using the definitions above / the words (or : terms) as defined previously (or : previously defined) / the notions established in the previous text" , or something like that.